# Using Variables from Imported files in Python

Tags: python, python-import, rfid

I am trying to get a variable and its value from another python file that has been `Imported` . I have the file **Main**.py and **Write**.py .In the Main file I am trying to get the variable `user_id` to equal the `new_id` variable from the Imported file **Write**.py .The `new_id` is creating a hash for the new user when they scan their tag (rfid). The issue is after the tag is scanned the Variable  `user_id` still remains empty. I think I might be grabbing the variable before the tag is scanned, any thoughts? I have posted the code below along with some comments.

```
from tkinter import *
#Second File
import Write
from tkcalendar import DateEntry
from firebase import firebase

data = {}

global user_id

# Firebase 
firebase= firebase.FirebaseApplication("https://xxxxxxx.firebaseio.com/",None)

# button click
def sub ():
    global user_id

    #setting Variables from user input
    name = entry_1.get()
    last = entry_2.get()
    number = phone.get()

    # issue is here
    try:
    #Calling Function from other file
        Write.scan()

        if Write.scan():
        #getting the New User Id
            user_id= new_id

            #User Info being sent to the Database 
            data = {
            'Name #': name,
            'Last': last,
            'Number': number,
            'Card #':user_id
            }
            results = firebase.post('xxxxxxxx/User',data)
           
     except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

**Write**.py

```
import string
from random import*
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from mfrc522 import SimpleMFRC522
reader = SimpleMFRC522()

#Function being called
def scan():
    try:
        #Creating user hash
        c = string.digits + string.ascii_letters
        new_id = "".join(choice(c) for x in range(randint(25,25)))
        print("Please Scan tag")

        #Writing to tag
        reader.write(new_id)
        if reader.write(new_id):
            print("Tag Scanned")
    
        else:
            print("Scan Tag First")
        print("Scanning Complete")

    finally:
        GPIO.cleanup()
```

Comment: you don't need a global. instead `return new_id` at the bottom of your scan function

Comment: @PaulH Yep that was it! Thanks for the help man.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the actual issue or just the formatting in here, but your indentations for the try: statement are wrong in your main file.